# Can not re show dojo grid in dialog after closed

Tags: dojo, dialog, grid

I create a dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid in a dojo dialog.
It works OK, when I click button first time, all display is OK.
But when I click "Cancel" to hide dialog, and then click button again to trigger that function and show dialog. The display is totally wrong, the grid header is not complete, and no data show. All grid is in gray.

Plz help me to re show dojo grid in Dialog.

```
<table dojoType="dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid" id="grid6" plugins="{indirectSelection: true, selectable: true, dnd: true, nestedSorting: true, loadingMessage: 'Loading...', errorMessage: 'An error exists within the data.' }" selectionMode="extended" class="popupDojoTable" style="height:200px;"  rowSelector="0px">
                            <colgroup span="3" noscroll="true"></colgroup>
                            <colgroup span="6"></colgroup>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th field="machType" width="60px">Machine<br />type</th>
                                    <th field="machSerNum" width="100px">Machine<br />serial<br />number</th>
                                    <th field="mesNum" width="80px" styles="text-align:right;">MES<br />number</th>
                                    <th field="bookType" width="60px">Book<br />type</th>
                                    <th field="machMod" width="80px">Machine<br />model</th>
                                    <th field="transType" width="80px">Transaction<br />type</th>
                                    <th field="effDte" width="80px">Effective<br />date</th>
                                    <th field="custNum" width="80px">Customer<br />number</th>
                                    <th field="assetPeriodNum" width="60px" styles="text-align:right;">Asset<br />period<br />number</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                             ...
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

Then I insert data by script. It get data from server by ajax, then show dialog "dialogRecordsOnHold" which contains grid.

```
dojo.xhrPost({
                              url: this.url,
                              handleAs: "json",
                              headers : {
                                  "Content-Type" : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                  "Accept" : "application/json"
                              },
                              postData : dojo.toJson({finEnterpNum:this.finEnterpNum, adjNum:this.adjNum}),
                            ....
                     load: function(data) {
                         var gridData = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({data:{items:data}});
                         dijit.byId('grid6').setStore(gridData);

                         // hide dialogProcessing
                         dijit.byId('dialogOpeningView').hide();
                         dijit.byId('dialogRecordsOnHold').show();
                     },
)};
```

Cancel button's function is so easy:

```
<button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" type="button" onclick="dijit.byId('grid6').setStore(null);dijit.byId('dialogRecordsOnHold').hide();">Cancel</button>
```

Comment: I have fix it by myself.
Change the code into:

 load: function(data) {
                         var gridData = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({data:{items:data}});
                         // hide dialogProcessing
                         dijit.byId('dialogOpeningView').hide();
                         dijit.byId('dialogRecordsOnHold').show();

                         dijit.byId('grid6').setStore(gridData);
                     },
)};

Answer (score 0):

I have fix it by myself.
Change the code into:

```
 load: function(data) { 
 // hide dialogProcessing 
dijit.byId('dialogOpeningView').hide();
 dijit.byId('dialogRecordsOnHold').show();
var gridData = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({data:{items:data}});
 dijit.byId('grid6').setStore(gridData);
 },
 )};
```